# Covert into date format in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a character field in the database where Date value is stored.
Now I need to convert this character Date field value in below format

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS
```

I am using below conversion for it, but it's not working

```
to_char(lastupdate,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

Could anyone please help out on this?

Comment: Not working, as in you're getting an error or a different output?

Comment: In which format you have stored the date value?

Comment: Tested on 11.2.0.3: ``TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
------------------------------------------
2014-01-17T11:03:19                        
``

Comment: @Incognito: I sm getting error that Invalid Number format

Comment: If you are storing a date value as a character literal, you first need to convert it to a value of date data type (`to_date()` do not include `"T"` literal in the format mask) and then back to character using `to_char()`

Comment: @Dba:I have stored the value in mm-dd-yyyy format

Answer (score 4):

As you are stored your `date` in character literal like `mm-dd-yyyy`, you first need to convert it to date data_type using `to_date` and then to character using `to_char` as suggested by Nicholas Krasnov. Try like this,

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM   <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the date as 2014-01-17 00:00:00:

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(last_update, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from <table>;
```